# Gallian: is it true that the well-ordering principle can't be proven from properties of arithmetic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, order-theory, natural-numbers

I just started reading Gallian's Abstract algebra and on page 3 it says "An important property of the integers...is the so-called Well Ordering Principle. *Since this property cannot be proved from the usual properties of arithmetic*, we will take it as an axiom". [my emphasis]

My question is, how can one (in this case the author) be so sure that the Well Ordering Principle cannot be proved from the properties of arithmetic. Is it possible to prove statements like this (i.e. the one in italics above). If so, what would a proof look like?

Comment: I sure hope he didn't claim the *integers* are well ordered...

Comment: OK, must be a typo on his part then. The integers are of course not well ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the well-ordering principle can be proved for *the natural numbers* in standard set theory, and you can find [a proof with google](http://www.cs.bsu.edu/homepages/fischer/math215/wellorder.pdf).

> If so, what would a proof look like?

Usually one uses set theory to prove induction, and then induction to prove well-ordering of $\Bbb N$.

I guess it depends on what the "properties of arithmetic" are that he refers to. If they are just the ring axioms for $\Bbb Z$, then yeah, that is not enough to prove well ordering of $\Bbb N$. Maybe Gallian just doesn't want to go so far afield into set theory, so he takes it as an axiom.

Comment: @AnalysisIncarnate The ring axioms for $\Bbb Z$ do not even *mention* order, so I can't imagine how one would talk about well ordering in any case.

Comment: @AnalysisIncarnate I can't offer any disproof of the existence of a proof without knowing what the axioms are that he is talking about. To successfully prove there is no proof, you'd have to give an example which isn't well-ordered by nevertheless satisfies the "arithmetic axioms" that he is talking about.

Comment: If by "that" you mean the link, then yes, that is a proof of the well-ordering theorem that only relies on set theory.

Comment: Depending on how you state the Well Ordering Principle, one way to see it can't come from the ring axioms of $\Bbb Z$ is that $\Bbb Z$ is not well ordered.  There is no minimal element.

Answer (score 0):

We can prove the well-ordering property *if we assume the principle of induction* (and similarly we can prove the principle of induction if we assume the well-ordering property).  For a proof, let $A\subset\mathbb{N}$, and suppose it has no least element.  Let $B$ be the set of all natural numbers $n$ such that $1,\dots,n\not\in A$.  Then clearly $1\in B$ (because if $1$ were in $A$, $1$ would be the smallest element of $A$).  Moreover, if $1,\dots,k\not\in A$, surely $k+1\not\in A$ (otherwise $k+1$ would be the smallest element of $A$), so $1,\dots,k+1\not\in A$.  In other words, if $k\in B$ then $k+1\in B$.  By induction we have $n\in B$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, hence $A=\emptyset$, completing the proof.